# How do I use the GitLab $CI_PIPELINE_IID in my gitlab-ci.yml file in my deployment.yaml file?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy the most recent image that was built in my GitLab CICD pipeline to my EKS cluster on AWS. In my gitlab-ci.yml file I use the $CI_PIPELINE_IID variable to tag the new images I am building and pushing to my gitlab container registry. The images build and deploy to my EKS cluster without failing, but when I check my EKS cluster resources for both the frontend and backend I see that the pulled image is "registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/backend:BACKEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID" with a status of "Waiting -InvalidImageName". How do I update my deployment so I can use the newest built image in my container registry?

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build_and_push
  - deploy
  
 
variables: 
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/ 
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2 
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" 

build_and_push_backend: 
  stage: build_and_push 
  image: docker:latest 
  services: enter image description here
    - docker:dind 
  before_script: 
    - docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u username -p password

  script: 
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/backend:BACKEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID ./backend

    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/backend:BACKEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID
   

build_and_push_frontend: 
  image: docker:latest 
  stage: build_and_push 
  services: 
    - docker:dind 
  before_script: 
    - docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u username -p password
  script: 
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/frontend:FRONTEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID ./frontend
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/frontend:FRONTEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: 
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl config use-context contxt/contxt:eks-agent # Set by GitLab Kubernetes Agent, if necessary
    - kubectl get nodes
    - kubectl get namespaces
    - kubectl delete namespace eks-sample-app
    - kubectl create namespace eks-sample-app
    - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml -n eks-sample-app
    - kubectl apply -f service.yaml -n eks-sample-app
    - kubectl get all 
    - kubectl get svc 
    - kubectl get pods
```

deployment.yml:

```
`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: react-frontend
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: react
 replicas: 2
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: react
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: react
       image: registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/frontend:FRONTEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID
       ports:
       - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: java-backend
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: java
 replicas: 2
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: java
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: java
       image: registry.gitlab.com/proj/repo/backend:BACKEND-$CI_PIPELINE_IID
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
       env:
       - name: MYSQL_HOST
         value: db
`
```

AWS EKS Error:

[AWS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab02o.jpg)

Working Container Registry Images:
[Container Registry Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klqs6.png)

I initially tried to use the $CI_PIPELINE_IID variable in my deployment.yml file like I did in my gitlab-ci.yml file, but the variable does not seem to pass to my EKS deployment as the same value. I expect each time my pipeline runs, first the image is built and push to the container registry with the newest $CI_PIPELINE_IID value, then in my deploy stage that new image that was built and pushed in the previous stage will be the one deployed to my EKS cluster using the deployment.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Any environment variable wont automatically substitute in deployment.yaml and you cannot pass any variables to "kubectl apply -f"'

"envsubst" command would have been a better option, but I see that in bitnami/kubectl image this utility isnt available.

So you can use "sed" command instead

```
sed -e "s/\$CI_PIPELINE_IID/$CI_PIPELINE_IID/" deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: How could I use the envsubst command?

Comment: That's fine. You can just use "sed" command. Give it a try.

Comment: the "sed" command worked, thanks!